# Basic understanding of cell cycle (mitosis) phase

Tags: genetics

Update
[image]

This is for a diploid cell (2n).

At G1, cell growth before the DNA is duplicated.

At S, DNA replicated. Chromosomes doubled!

At G2, cell growth

Then Mitosis; Prophase, Metaphase, Anaphase, Telophase, Cytokinesis

Could anyone explain if the chart is correct or incorrect?

Comment: Closevoters: please read the actual text of the close reason. The OP here has *clearly* shown their attempt at an answer.

Comment: I agree with @terdon, this might be not the greatest question but there is no reason to close it.

Comment: can you explain what mlcl means?

Comment: Further one chromosome does not contain the whole genome just a chuck of it (however sometimes a whole genome can be on one chromsoome in the case of simple life forms such as bacteria) can you please specify  the organism you are talking about?

Comment: Mlcl= Molecule. and idk what organism is. It wasnt specify. Initial chromosome number was 6 (which i believe 2n=6).

Comment: how do you count the number of genome copies?

Comment: All chromosomes form the genome (https://research.cip.cgiar.org/confluence/display/potatogene/What+is+DNA,+a+gene,+a+chromosome+and+a+genome) ps you can tag me next time so I will get a notification (using: @Rick Beeloo)

Comment: @RickBeeloo Thank you so much for the link. It was definitely helpful. So since chromosome has 6 according to my question, then number of genome copies would be 6 in G1 phase. I know number of chromosomes increase in anaphase (# of chromosomes would be 12 in anaphase). I'd like to know if im on the right track.

Comment: The total set of chromosomes (in this case thus 6) is the genome (maybe the answer to this question will help you: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/24126/do-human-cells-contain-only-one-copy-of-the-genome and read the comments) so 6 chromosomes is 1 genome copy and 12 chromosomes are 2 genomes copies (only for mitosis then)

Comment: @RickBeeloo i have updated my answer. I think i get what you're saying. i see that in this case, only in anaphase the number of genome copies would be 2 since there is 12 chromosomes if 2n=6. On other cases, number of genome copies would be only 1 since there is 6 chromosomes in G1,G2,Metaphase, and after cytokinesis. Correct?

Comment: I think your chromosomes and genome numbers are correct now (you can look a this great explanation about human chromsomes during mitosis http://datbootcamp.com/biology-strategy/chromosome-and-chromatid-numbers-during-mitosis-and-meiosis/ ) I'm not sure what you mean with number of DNA molecules?

Comment: You might want to clarify that "DNA molecule" here refers to the entire double helix, with both strands. Since the strands are not covalently bound to each other, some would say that the double helix is made up of two molecules, one for each strand.

Answer (score 1):

**# DNA molecules**
A chromosome can have either 1 DNA molecule or 2, this depends upon what stage the cell is at that moment. It actually might help to know what chromatids are:

> A chromatid (Greek khrōmat- 'color' + -id) is one copy of a newly
>   copied chromosome which is still joined to the original copy by a
>   single centromere. ([wiki](http://A%20chromatid%20(Greek%20khr%C5%8Dmat-%20'color'%20+%20-id)%20is%20one%20copy%20of%20a%20newly%20copied%20chromosome%20which%20is%20still%20joined%20to%20the%20original%20copy%20by%20a%20single%20centromere.))

This means that the number of chromatids is directly related to the number of DNA molecuels.

> Before replication, one chromosome is composed of one DNA molecule.
>   Following replication, each chromosome is composed of two DNA
>   molecules; in other words, DNA replication itself increases the amount
>   of DNA but does not increase the number of chromosomes.([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatid))

[image]
We can now add another row which indicates the DNA molecules, chromatids are directly related to the number of DNA molecules thus from left to right:

```
 46        92         92        46
```

These are the basics, now in some more detail about mitosis:
[image]
So based on the number of chromatids and your chromosome number you can figure out the nubmer of chormatids and thus the number of DNA molecules:
Thus before replication **(G1) = 6**, then after S phase **(G2) = 12**, then **metaphase = 12** and after **cytokinesis = 6.** Just as in your table so that part is correct!

---

**# of chromosomes**
You can read these from the table, however I think it's important to understand what is happening. In simple words chromatids and chromosomes are related in this sense:

> It is only when sister chromatids separate – a step signaling that
>   anaphase has begun – that each chromatid is considered a separate,
>   individual chromosome ([source](http://datbootcamp.com/biology-strategy/chromosome-and-chromatid-numbers-during-mitosis-and-meiosis/))

The phase in which the chromatids seperate is called anaphase, so after this seperation: 
[image]
we consider the previoulsy chromatids as chromosomes. Thus anaphase and telophase contain the double number of chromosomes as the amount you started with. However anaphase and telophase are not mentioned in your table. So let's go back to the phases in your table. During metphase the chromatids are still **connected** to each other, meaning that we consider them as one chromosome (the same is true for G1 and G2, because we did not seperate anything). So that part of you table is correct too.

---

**# genome copies**

> The human genome is the **complete set of nucleic acid sequence** for
>   humans (Homo sapiens), encoded as DNA within the 23 chromosome pairs
>   in cell nuclei and in a small DNA molecule found within individual
>   mitochondria.([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_genome))

However read [this question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/24126/do-human-cells-contain-only-one-copy-of-the-genome) and the answers,  some say 1 genome per cell and some say two genomes per cell, this confuses me too so I'm not sure about this one, however based on the wiki it would say that 2n = one genome, which would make sense because the two pair of chromosomes are not equal and when saying you have two genomes per cell you are actually counting mitochondrial DNA twice.

Comment: I think the number of genome copies is correct on my chart. What do you think?

Comment: I think it is @Chris